# java наследование и private

Tags: java

Есть 2 класса,КлассА и КлассБ
ClassA.java->

```
 package com.company;
    public class ClassA {
    
        private int x;
        private int y;
    
        public ClassA() {
            x = 0;
            y = 0;
        }
        public ClassA(int x1, int y1) {
            x = x1;
            y = y1;
        }
    
    
    
        public void print() {
            System.out.print(x + " " + y + " ");
        }
    
        public String toString() {
            return x + " " + y + " ";
        }
    
        public void set(int x1, int y1) {
            x = x1;
            y = y1;
        }
    }
```

ClassB.java->

```
  package com.company;
    
    public class ClassB extends ClassA{
    
       private int z;
       public ClassB() {
           x = 0;
           y = 0;
           z = 0;
       }
    
       public ClassB(int x1,int y1,int z1) {
           x = x1;
           y = y1;
           z = z1;
       }
    
       public void print(){
           System.out.println(x + " " + y + " " + z);
       }
       public String toString() {
           return x + " " + y + " " + z;
       }
    
       public void set(int x1,int y1,int z1) {
           x = x1;
           y = y1;
           z = z1;
       }
    }
```

На Классе А есть 2 переменных с модификаторм private.Класс Б наследует Класс А,можно ли через класс Б  получить доступ к переменным с модификатором private который является переменными класса А.(Если компилировать в этом виде то выдает ошибку что Класс Б не может использовать переменные с мод. private который является переменными класса А)

Comment: просто так нет, нельзя. Либо пишите метод типа getXXX() для получения значения, либо делайте поля видимыми, либо самый дурацкий вариант - используйте рефлексию.

Comment: Спасибо!попробую

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для доступа дочерним классам используется модификатор protected.

А вообще, можно всё переписать не используя x и y:

```
public class ClassB extends ClassA{

   private int z;
   public ClassB() {
       super();
       z = 0;
   }

   public ClassB(int x1,int y1) {
       super(x1, y1);
       z = 0;
   }

   public ClassB(int x1,int y1,int z1) {
       super(x1, y1);
       z = z1;
   }

   public void print(){
       super.print();
       System.out.println(z);
   }
   public String toString() {
       return super.toString() + z;
   }

   public void set(int x1,int y1,int z1) {
       super.set(x1, y1);
       z = z1;
   }
}
```

Лучше переписать метод `print()`, чтобы он использовал свой `toString()`

Answer (score 0):

переменные `private` работают только в классе. Используй `public` или вообще без модификатора доступа.

Если тебе нужно **сохранить значения класса А** и **использовать в классе B**, то **добавить** `final`

Comment: Причем тут final не понял) Но спасибо за ответ!